# How do I reset screen timeout from my application?

Tags: android, android-activity, timeout

I have an activity and a service. Whenever I start the service via a button from the activity, I set the screen timeout to one second, so that the screen goes off pretty quick.

Here's the line that does that:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1000);
```

Now, my normal timeout is 30 seconds, so I COULD simply write something like this, in the button which stops the service:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 30000);
```

But, if anyone else uses this app, they might have a screen timeout of one minute, for example. My question is: how do I set the timeout to the device's "default" number of seconds/minutes?

Answer (score 0):

First get device screen time out in your service or activity before setting it using

```
int timeout = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), 
                         Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, Default);
```

where default is any value to set as default Ex : 30000

after that set its value when u want you can put below code in your activity's `onDestroy()` method.

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, timeout);
```

Comment: I get an error at "Default". Don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @Vlad Pintea see my edited answer, set any integer value for default